# Bootstrap Angular Components in HTML files

Tags: angular

I use Angular on my frontend side with Django. Note that I don't use Angular for SPA, but use Django to serve templates. Problem is that I need to inject some angular components in templates but as I can see I can only bootstrap one root module.

This is my `app.module.ts`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ContactComponent,
    AboutComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [ContactComponent, AboutComponent]
})
```

I want to inject ContactComponent `<contact></contact>` in `contact.html`, and AboutComponent `<about></about>` in `about.html`.

After ng-build I get following error:

*The selector "contact" did not match any elements(…)* in `about.html`
*The selector "about" did not match any elements(…)* in `contact.html`

How can I achieve this, to exports angular components and use it in html files. Maybe Angular is build only for SPA or I am missing something.

I use Angular version 4 in my project which is generated through **angular-cli** (don't use SystemJS anymore).

Comment: I doubt you can do that to be honest, and if you find the way to hack that, I am super sure will  bring you problems in the near future.

Comment: for this to work, the `Contact` and `About` would each need to be their own Module, and they would not know about nor be able to communicate with each other.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is right in programming terms. You can bootstrap multiple modules using declaration metadata as you are doing. So your error is NOT comming because the code you shown. You should check imports, reaches and selectors. Anyways.

The sense of bootstraping one only root component is an agreement that give more sense to modularity. And you have some other ways to bootstrap multiple modules

If the sense of your module is more like an individual app you can isolate them with their `main.ts` doing the bootstrap (each one) 
main.ts

```
import {bootstrap}    from '@angular2/platform/browser'
import {FirstComponent} from './my-first.component'

bootstrap(FirstComponent);
```

and then import in your HTML.

```
 System.import('first/main').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
 System.import('second/main').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

If the sense is to have as a "package" you can have a main module that acts as barrel, helper or how you want to name it. It imports your modules

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [First],
  exports: [First]
})
export class FirstModule

@NgModule({
  declarations: [Second],
  exports: [Second]
})
export class SecondModule

@NgModule({
 imports: [FirstModule, SecondModule],
 exports: [FirstModule, SecondModule]
})
export class BarrelModule
```

You can use this only module when you require all of them.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I didn't say, but I generate project with angular-cli. And angular-cli don't use SystemJS as bundler now, they switched to webpack so I don't think this import in HTML will work...